# the unique point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that minimize $f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^m\|x-y_k\|$ is exists.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $y_1 \cdots y_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \geq 2, m \geq 3$) and with Euclidean distance, I want to prove the following proposition.

the unique point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that minimize $f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^m\|x-y_k\|$ is exists.

I think I should prove $f$ is strongly convex function and the point $x_0$ exists and $f$ is local minimum value on it. However something wrong and I am struggling with this proposition.

Please some help. Thank you!

(Sorry, if $y_1 \cdots y_m$ can be on the same straight line, the point $x_0$ is not unique...if $y_1 \cdots y_m$ are not on the same straight line, can we prove this?)

Comment: $x_0$ is *not necessarily* unique (let $m$ be even and $y_k=y_0+kd$ for some $y_0,d\in\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: Thank you a lot. If $y_1 \cdots y_m$ are not on the same straight line, is it able to prove the proposition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

For one dimension, the mean deviation of $y_k, k=1,2,3,...n$ about a point $x$ is defined as
$$MD=\frac{1}{n} \sum_k^{n} |y_k-x|$$
MD is the least if $x$ is the median of the data $y_k$.

If $n$ is odd $x=y_{(n+1)/2}$ so $$f(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{n} |y_k-x|$$ will have a local min at this point.

If $n$ is even then there will be two medians $x=y_{n/2}$, $x=y_{n/2+1}$ and $f(x)$ will attend the least and equal value value at these two points but there wont be a local minimum.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If $y_1 \cdots y_m$ are not on the same straight line, can you prove the proposition?

Comment: $y_k$ are just arbitrary numbers like 2,5,7.8. 9, they need not fall on any curve or line.

Comment: $y_k$ is the points of $\mathbb{R}^n(n \geq 2)$, right?

Comment: $R^1$ means data is like one dimensional array, $R^2$ is collection of data as $(x1,y1), (x2,y2).....$ $R^3$ means collection of triplets : $(x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2),...$ . So I have hinted youu about $R^1$.